# MkMapView Pin with action

Tags: xcode, mkmapview

I'm using MkMapView and I need to send the user to another view if he clicks the pin I've added on the map, is there any method to do this?

Comment: Did you look at the delegate methods for MKAnnotationView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

Check out the docs on [MKMapViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:)